# Enter a date by a loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops, if-statement

I want a loop to check for 'FirstName" if first name is there, then enter an end date put in by the end user. If no first name, stop loop.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('file.xls')
print('Please enter the end date')
eDate = input()
new_date = pd.to_datetime(eDate)
df.loc[i,'EndDate']
```

Where I have 'i', I want that to be my if statement result. I'm not sure how to write the if statement

Comment: Please read this before posting; [ask], [mcve]

Comment: Look more closely at the words you wrote here: "...check for 'FirstName' if first name is there...". How can you translate this into a python statement?

Comment: I wrote it that way so its easier to understand what I'm trying to do. I'm new to python and I'm still learning data frames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly what your xls file has/looks like. so your condition to check for FirstName should probably be different. So I just put in a very basic check. Also, you might want to add how you want the date to be entered so that the .to_datetime works correctly

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('file.xls')

eDate = input('Please enter the end date: ')
new_date = pd.to_datetime(eDate)

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    #put your check for firstname here. 
    #Not sure what your xls file looks like, so something like...
    if row['FirstName'] != '':
        df.loc[i,'EndDate'] = eDate
```

This code will continue through the dataframe. if no first name, it'll be None. and if you want it to stop the loop if no firstname as stated above, throw in the else statement and as soon as it comes across a row with no first name, it stops.

```
if row['FirstName'] != '':
     df.loc[i,'EndDate'] = eDate
else:
    break
```